# WooCommerce - Remove attribute pagination, or show more results per page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a enormous list of bra-sizes which I need to re-order, but the WooCommerce attribute page lists this in 3 different pages. Thus making it kind of difficult to order them.

I was wondering if there's a way to just remove the pagination on the Attributes Terms page.

[Screenshot](https://i.gyazo.com/2de19df69e87956d7b9872a367c917fa.png)

**EDIT SOLUTION:**

WordPress has a built in function to change the amount of items you list on a page.
In the upper right corner underneath your username there's a tab called "screen options", if you click this a modal pops open and you're able to the value in the field next to "Amount of items per page".
This should help you to view more items!

Comment: I believe it would be the best if you would ask here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ as this site it is dedicated to Wordpress questions

Comment: Alright thanks, I've posted my question there:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/281655/woocommerce-remove-attribute-pagination-or-show-more-results-per-page

Comment: You're welcome :)

Comment: check the "page options" button at the top of the screen, you may be able to increase the page size there.